# CGPathRelease crash app after CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation, quartz-core

I have one pan gesture recognizer to perform some work.When the gesture state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`,perform `CABasicAnimation` .The code:

```
CGPathRef path = [self pathToAnimateWithX:0 andY:0];
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation  animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = (__bridge id _Nullable)(dragLayer.path);
animation.toValue = (__bridge id)path;
animation.duration = 0.5;
[dragLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"dd"];
```

This code works fine.No perblem. But when I release the `path` like this:

```
CGPathRelease(path);
```

My app will crash with no crash information.

---

Update: here is `pathToAnimateWith:`method

```
- (CGPathRef)pathToAnimateWithX:(CGFloat)x andY:(CGFloat)y {

     UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
     // configure path
     [path closePath];
     return path.CGPath;
 }
```

Comment: Because you are mismanaging the memory. Show the implementation of `pathToAnimateWithX:andY:`, please.

Comment: To get crash information, make sure you have the exception breakpoint enabled.

Comment: You needn't release the `path` by `CGPathRelease(path);`. The `CGPathRef` is belongs to `UIBezierPath` and `toValue` property of `CABasicAnimation` has strong reference to it. `UIBezierPath` and `CABasicAnimation` will release it properly.

Comment: @KudoCC thanks for your help!